# javascript/jQuery call execute function once prior function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the easiest way to execute a function (resetMenuPosition()) in javascript (or jQuery) only when the prior function (collapseExpandMainMenu(this)) is complete.

ORIGINAL CODE

```
$('.trmenuClass').click(function () {
    $.when(collapseExpandMainMenu(this))
     .done(function () {
         resetMenuPosition();
     });
});
```

I've tried different variations of jQuery but I think I am mis-using jQuery as I don't completely grasp the idea of deferred objects.

Any javascript or jQuery suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
-Tim

EDITED TO INCLUDE collapseExpandMainMenu(this) CODE

```
function collapseExpandMainMenu(i, callback) {
    isCollapsing = ($(i).find('div').attr('class')) == 'minusSign';
    currentScrollTop = $('#contents').scrollTop();

    var fav, Dash, Conn, Hire, Retain, Activityreports;
    var favSubmnuHt = 0, dashSubmnuHt = 0, connSubmnuHt = 0, hireSubmnuHt = 0, retainSubmnuHt = 0, activityreportsSubmnuHt = 0;

    /*submenu height determination*/
    $('.trmenuClass').each(function () {
        if ($('tr.favtrClass').toggle().is(":visible")) {
            fav = 1;
        }
        else {
            fav = 0;
        }

        if ($('tr.dashboardtrClass').toggle().is(":visible")) {
            Dash = 1;
        }
        else {
            Dash = 0;
        }

        if ($('tr.connecttrClass').toggle().is(":visible")) {
            Conn = 1;
        }
        else {
            Conn = 0;
        }

        if ($('tr.hiretrClass').toggle().is(":visible")) {
            Hire = 1;
        }
        else {
            Hire = 0;
        }

        if ($('tr.retaintrClass').toggle().is(":visible")) {
            Retain = 1;
        }
        else {
            Retain = 0;
        }

        if ($('tr.activityreportstrClass').toggle().is(":visible")) {
            Activityreports = 1;
        }
        else {
            Activityreports = 0;
        }

    })

    /*This gets the height of each dynamically created submenu along with bottom border*/
    var favBottomBorder = 0; var dashBottomBorder = 0; var connectBottomBorder = 0; var hireBottomBorder = 0;
    var retainBottomBorder = 0; var activityreportsBottomBorder = 0;
    $('.favtrClass').each(function () {
        favSubmnuHt = favSubmnuHt + 35;
        favBottomBorder = favBottomBorder + 1;
    })

    $('.dashboardtrClass').each(function () {
        dashSubmnuHt = dashSubmnuHt + 35;
        dashBottomBorder = dashBottomBorder + 1;
    })

    $('.connecttrClass').each(function () {
        connSubmnuHt = connSubmnuHt + 35;
        connectBottomBorder = connectBottomBorder + 1;
    })

    $('.hiretrClass').each(function () {
        hireSubmnuHt = hireSubmnuHt + 35;
        hireBottomBorder = hireBottomBorder + 1;
    })

    $('.retaintrClass').each(function () {
        retainSubmnuHt = retainSubmnuHt + 35;
        retainBottomBorder = retainBottomBorder + 1;
    })

    $('.activityreportstrClass').each(function () {
        activityreportsSubmnuHt = activityreportsSubmnuHt + 35;
        activityreportsBottomBorder = activityreportsBottomBorder + 1;
    })

    /*submenu height determination */
    var varFav = favSubmnuHt - favBottomBorder;
    var varDash = dashSubmnuHt - dashBottomBorder;
    var varConn = connSubmnuHt - connectBottomBorder;
    var varHire = hireSubmnuHt - hireBottomBorder;
    var varRetain = retainSubmnuHt - retainBottomBorder;
    var varActivityreports = activityreportsSubmnuHt - activityreportsBottomBorder;
    var rowCount = ($('#contents tr').length) * 35;

    /*determination which submenu is open and which is closed*/
    if (fav == 1) { favSubmnuHt; }
    else if (fav == 0) { rowCount = rowCount - favSubmnuHt; }

    if (Dash == 1) { dashSubmnuHt; }
    else if (Dash == 0) { rowCount = rowCount - dashSubmnuHt; }

    if (Conn == 1) { connSubmnuHt; }
    else if (Conn == 0) { rowCount = rowCount - connSubmnuHt; }

    if (Hire == 1) { hireSubmnuHt; }
    else if (Hire == 0) { rowCount = rowCount - hireSubmnuHt; }

    if (Retain == 1) { retainSubmnuHt; }
    else if (Retain == 0) { rowCount = rowCount - retainSubmnuHt; }

    if (Activityreports == 1) { activityreportsSubmnuHt; }
    else if (Activityreports == 0) { rowCount = rowCount - activityreportsSubmnuHt; }


    var heightOfSubMenuCombined = 0;
    var idTotoggleSubMenu = $(i).closest('tr').attr('id');  // changes from "this" to "i"
    if (idTotoggleSubMenu == "favoritestrId") {
        $('tr.favtrClass').toggle(browserVar, function () { });
        if (fav == 1) {
            rowCount = rowCount - favSubmnuHt;
            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });

            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);

            }
        }
        else if (fav == 0) {
            rowCount = rowCount + varFav;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);

            }
        }
        /*Code to toggle plus and minus sign*/
        if ($('#favoritesMinusSignId').hasClass('minusSign')) {
            $('#favoritesMinusSignId').addClass('plusSign').removeClass('minusSign');
        }
        else if ($('#favoritesMinusSignId').hasClass('plusSign')) {
            $('#favoritesMinusSignId').addClass('minusSign').removeClass('plusSign');
        }

    }
    else if (idTotoggleSubMenu == "dashboardtrId") {
        /*Code to toggle submenu and make bottom scrolling arrow slide up and down*/

        $('tr.dashboardtrClass').toggle(browserVar, function () { });

        if (Dash == 1) {
            rowCount = rowCount - dashSubmnuHt;
            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);

            }
        }
        else if (Dash == 0) {
            rowCount = rowCount + varDash;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }

        /*Code to toggle plus and minus sign*/
        if ($('#dashboardMinusSignId').hasClass('minusSign')) {
            $('#dashboardMinusSignId').addClass('plusSign').removeClass('minusSign');
        }
        else if ($('#dashboardMinusSignId').hasClass('plusSign')) {
            $('#dashboardMinusSignId').addClass('minusSign').removeClass('plusSign');
        }

    }
    else if (idTotoggleSubMenu == "connecttrId") {
        /*Code to toggle submenu and make bottom scrolling arrow slide up and down*/
        $('tr.connecttrClass').toggle(browserVar, function () { });

        if (Conn == 1) {
            rowCount = rowCount - connSubmnuHt;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }
        else if (Conn == 0) {
            rowCount = rowCount + varConn;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }

        /*Code to toggle plus and minus sign*/
        if ($('#connectMinusSignId').hasClass('minusSign')) {
            $('#connectMinusSignId').addClass('plusSign').removeClass('minusSign');
        }
        else if ($('#connectMinusSignId').hasClass('plusSign')) {
            $('#connectMinusSignId').addClass('minusSign').removeClass('plusSign');
        }
    }
    else if (idTotoggleSubMenu == "hiretrId") {
        /*Code to toggle submenu and make bottom scrolling arrow slide up and down*/
        $('tr.hiretrClass').toggle(browserVar, function () { });

        if (Hire == 1) {
            rowCount = rowCount - hireSubmnuHt;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }
        else if (Hire == 0) {
            rowCount = rowCount + varHire;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }

        /*Code to toggle plus and minus sign*/
        if ($('#hireMinusSignId').hasClass('minusSign')) {
            $('#hireMinusSignId').addClass('plusSign').removeClass('minusSign');
        }
        else if ($('#hireMinusSignId').hasClass('plusSign')) {
            $('#hireMinusSignId').addClass('minusSign').removeClass('plusSign');
        }

    }
    else if (idTotoggleSubMenu == "retaintrId") {
        /*Code to toggle submenu and make bottom scrolling arrow slide up and down*/
        $('tr.retaintrClass').toggle(browserVar, function () { });

        if (Retain == 1) {
            rowCount = rowCount - retainSubmnuHt;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }
        else if (Retain == 0) {
            rowCount = rowCount + varRetain;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }

        /*Code to toggle plus and minus sign*/
        if ($('#retainMinusSignId').hasClass('minusSign')) {
            $('#retainMinusSignId').addClass('plusSign').removeClass('minusSign');
        }
        else if ($('#retainMinusSignId').hasClass('plusSign')) {
            $('#retainMinusSignId').addClass('minusSign').removeClass('plusSign');
        }
    }
    else if (idTotoggleSubMenu == "activityreportstrId") {
        /*Code to toggle submenu and make bottom scrolling arrow slide up and down*/
        $('tr.activityreportstrClass').toggle(browserVar, function () { });

        if (Activityreports == 1) {
            rowCount = rowCount - activityreportsSubmnuHt;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }
        else if (Activityreports == 0) {
            rowCount = rowCount + varActivityreports;

            if (rowCount > $('#contents').height()) {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "visible" });
            }
            else {
                $('.scrollDownArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $('.scrollUpArrow').hide();
                $('.scrollUpArrow').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                $(document).ready(resizingScrollbar);
            }
        }

        /*Code to toggle plus and minus sign*/
        if ($('#activityreportsMinusSignId').hasClass('minusSign')) {
            $('#activityreportsMinusSignId').addClass('plusSign').removeClass('minusSign');
        }
        else if ($('#activityreportsMinusSignId').hasClass('plusSign')) {
            $('#activityreportsMinusSignId').addClass('minusSign').removeClass('plusSign');
        }
    }

    //setTimeout(function () {
        callback.call();
    //}, 400);
}
```

CODE USING JQUERY .THEN

```
$('.trmenuClass').click(function () {
    (collapseExpandMainMenu(this)).then(
        function () { resetMenuPosition(); },
        function () { alert("Please close and re-open the menu."); }
    );
});
```

OPENING LINES OF resetMenuPosition()

```
    console.log('#menuTableId.height: ' + $('#menuTableId').css('height').replace(/px/g, ''));
    alert('pause');
    console.log('#menuTableId.height: ' + $('#menuTableId').css('height').replace(/px/g, ''));
```

Comment: what does collapseExpandMainMenu do? is it a jQuery animation?

Comment: You will have to show us the code for `collapseExpandMainMenu` in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Is `collapseExpandMainMenu` returning a deferred object?

Comment: @ianpgall, collapseExpandMainMenu basically collapses/expands sub-menu items when a main menu item is clicked.  The specific problem I am running into is the menu is not completely redone after the click before I am looking for the entire menu height in the second function.  Granted the code in collapseExpandMainMenu was poorly written and could use some refactoring.

Comment: Are you able to edit the collapseExpandMainMenu function? If so, can you provide the code for it, as the others have suggested? It might be easier to pass a callback to the function and have that run in the complete of the animation.

Comment: @ianpgall & jfriend00 - Original question edited to include collapseExpandMainMenu code.  I inherited this code, and I am able to edit it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `collapseExpandMainMenu` needs to return a `$.Deferred()` (or a promise) object and resolve/reject when it is finished. Here's a simple example:

```
var collapseExpandMainMenu = function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function () {
        // some processing
        deferred.resolve('success!');
    }, 5000);

    return deferred.promise();
};

$.when(collapseExpandMainMenu(this))
    .done(function (message) {
        console.log(message); // logs "success!" after 5 seconds
    }
);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3sGZh/

Side note: a promise is a deferred that cannot be resolved/rejected - you give this to consumers so they can respond to resolve/reject, but not execute it themselves.

Comment: Is it possible to have the second function run immediately after the first one is complete instead of waiting for a set timeout period?

Comment: @TimS.: Nobody said you'd need to use a timeout. Just resolve it in the callback function of your asynchronous functionality - show us your code of `collapseExpandMainMenu`

Comment: @jbabey: Why do you use `$.when`?

Comment: @Bergi it was in his original example. If it were me, i'd use `collapseExpandMainMenu(this).then(...);` instead.

Comment: @TimS. the setTimeout was to illustrate an asynchronous delay. you don't need to do it in your function.

Comment: @jbabey, I implemented your solution including the .then approach but I am still having the same issue.  When I get to my second function (resetMenuPosition) the work from the first function is not complete.  I can recognize this by writing the table height to the console twice with an alert in between.  The size of the table changes.  Maybe what I am trying to do is not possible without a set timeout?  I've attached some additional code.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a callback :

```
$('.trmenuClass').on('click', function () {
    collapseExpandMainMenu(this, function() {
        console.log('success!'); // logs "success!" when animation completes
        resetMenuPosition();
    });
});

function collapseExpandMainMenu(elem, callback) {
     //do your stuff first, then call the callback
     $(elem).fadeIn(1000, function() {
          callback.call(); //waits until animation is complete
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly.  Although ideally I'd like to call the second function upon the initial function completing instead of waiting for some fixed timeout period.  Is this possible?

Comment: @TimS. - Yes, you can call the `callback` function whenever your function is complete, I just used a timeout to demonstrate it. You can call the callback either at the bottom of the code or in some other callback for a jQuery function etc, depends on how the `collapseExpandMainMenu` function is set up, and what the last performed action in that function is, and then you just call the callback when everything else is completed. Edited my answer to show another version ?

Comment: Will this approach work for multiple clicks?  For example the user may expand/collapse the same item or they may collapse multiple main menu items all without a page refresh.  I only see the console log logging the first instance.  After that I am getting my second function running too soon?